# Unable to install IBM Worklight plugin in Eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt, ibm-mobilefirst

While installing `IBM Worklight` on Eclipse ADT( The Android Editor I downloaded from Google) I get following error:

```
org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas 1.2.2.v201304110304 is unknown in the solver!
org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas 1.2.2.v201304110304 is unknown in the solver!
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Worklight 2 versions of Eclipse:

1. Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)
2. Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)

Use one of the above.

Comment: @Volatil3, Eclipse Indigo is no longer supported.

Comment: SO this error due to same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336244/unable-to-install-ibm-worklight-plugin-due-to-dependencies

Comment: @Darn so I install Entire Eclipse Software Again? Is there no workaround?

Comment: There is no workaround. Worklight does not support Eclipse Indigo. Please read the documentation; it clearly states this.

Comment: I did read this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-aim1206-working-with-worklight-1/index.html?ca=drs

Comment: @Volatil3, full list of system requirements by release: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838