# Unable to install IBM Worklight plugin due to dependencies

Tags: jquery, eclipse, adt, ibm-mobilefirst

I am  installing `IBM Worklight` on Eclipse Indigo. It asks to install following dependencies:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.1.0.01-20140418-0637 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140418-0637)
  Missing requirement: Mobile Patterns 1.1.0.v20140418_0503 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.mobile.patterns 1.1.0.v20140418_0503) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.resources [3.8.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rich Page Editor - jQuery extensions 2.0.100.v20140418_0503 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery 2.0.100.v20140418_0503)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.rpe.mobile.patterns [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: jQuery Web Tools 1.1.0.v20140418_0503 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.v20140418_0503)
    To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.jquery [2.0.100.v20140418_0503]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.1.0.01-20140418-0637 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140418-0637)
    To: com.ibm.webtools.jquery.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,2.0.0)
```

Why is it not fetching itself? Where to download it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worklight 6.1.0.0 does not support Eclipse Indigo.

Please use:

1. Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2), or
2. Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)

See [System Requirements](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/)